# Console app skeleton with input and output that is reusable

Tags: c#, .net, input, output, console-application

I have made countless console applications since I started coding. Sometimes you need to test something quickly, other times you want to make some simple helper program. In any case you always need some kind of interaction with the program and every time it feels like you are reinventing the wheel.

**So my question is:**

Does someone know of a console application skeleton? By that I mean a console application that already takes care of all the things you might expect from a console application.

1. Input command parsing with as many arguments as you want that map to methods in your classes for example.
2. Output depending on the input. Both when you type something that is expected and unexpected.
3. Easy way to add your custom classes and connect them to the skeleton app.

**P.S. I have found this one:**

[Link to a console app skeleton that is nice, but has limitations.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/816301/Csharp-Building-a-Useful-Extensible-NET-Console-Ap) 
It is very nice but it requires everything to be static among other things.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest an alternative for those countless console applications just to test something?

I use linqpad (https://www.linqpad.net/) as I hate all these throw away projects just to try something. You can define a basic query (template) and clone it each time.

It even supports NuGet packages and adding your own references.

Comment: I know LinqPad. I agree to what you say. Unfortunately, it only helps with one part of what I provided as an example and that is it. It is also a commercial product. That should have been a comment since it does not address the question I asked. I actually want a skeleton application instead of an alternative solution. Thanks for taking the time though.